# Twitter Overlapping with other text and icons

Tags: html, css, twitter

My current problem looks like this:

[image]

[Current Code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/513f901cead09169581d)

There is some script in there that I could not get into the screenshot.

I am wanting the twitter feed to go on the far left (in line with the rest of the text, and also a few logos centered horizontally and vertically on the right with a header above them.

Comment: you have to skip a line, and indent the code four spaces for it to display

Comment: I did that.... most of it showed in the preview but the script in the twitter part screwed it up.

Comment: sorry missed the link to current code.  However its still really hard to read: .... use a gist (https://gist.github.com/) or jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: updated the original post!